# Marshall Video Cameras and BMD ATEM

Tags: video, camera, production

I've been looking at some of the Marshall Video gear to be used with my BlackMagic ATEM TV Studio.

I'm wondering if anyone else has used any of these? Specifically the CV550-CS/B
http://www.marshall-usa.com/optical/cameras/2-megapixel-miniature/CV550-CS-CSB.php

I'd like to give them a shot but I'm confused on which one I need. I pretty sure the atem only uses 59.94 cameras but I know my go pros only put out 30p output and thats what I use currently.

Also does anyone have any experience with the Marshall cameras?

Comment: I'm confused.  So you have an ATEM and some go-pros, you use them together, you're sure the go-pros are 30p, but you're also sure the ATEM only supports 59.94?  What kind of go-pros? Hero 2, 3, 4, black, silver?  We're considering getting an ATEM, but I didn't realize it only supports such a short list of framerates.  Does it let you use mixed framerate sources?

Comment: I'm sure the gopros run at 30p cause you have to set them at at to get them to work with the atem at 1080i5994. Thats a go pro issue, and to be honest, I am always a little scared the gopro wont work. I do use a converter box with them too. The atem allows for 1080i59.94 and 720p59.94. You can not mix framerates. For me, not an issue, just looking to get beyond the go pros.

Comment: I will say that there appears to be firmware issues and other issues too with gopros and the atem. It's never worked 100% for me.